# Flex : AdvancedDataGrid columns dataProvider?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a AdvancedDataGrid, defined as:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="mainGrid" width="200" height="200" designViewDataType="flat" >
    <mx:columns>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

I am adding dynamically the columns to the grid, and the main question is:

- How to setup an array or vector as dataprovider to each Column?

P.S.
this function I am using to fill up the data:

```
private function buildUpTheGrid() : void    {

    masterColumns = new Array();
    masterData    = new Array();

    var tempColumn : AdvancedDataGridColumn;


    for( var iY : int = 0; iY < columsCount; iY++ )                 
    {
        masterData.push( new Array() );
        tempColumn           = new AdvancedDataGridColumn();
        tempColumn.width     = 20;

        for( var iX : int = 0; iX < rowsCount; iX++ )
            masterData[ iY ].push( iX );

    //  tempColumn.dataField = ???
        masterColumns.push( tempColumn );
    }

    mainGrid.columns = masterColumns;
    mainGrid.validateNow();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer to your question "How to setup an array or vector as dataprovider to each Column ?": You cannot.

The data 'views' in flex are all row based, not column based.  So, for this to work, you'll need to transform your columns into rows.  It's a fairly simple algorithm that I'm sure you can figure out.

As for adding the columns dynamically, you just need to add the columns to an array and then set that array in the 'columns' property of the grid.  You'll need to set a 'dataField' property on the column for it to know which data property to display from the row data you've just transformed.

Comment: i tried this @J_A_X, i have created an Array of Arrays, and set the array as dataProvider to the grid, but each column which i am creating require string for dataField... which i dont know how to setup into this very case.

Comment: Don't create an array of arrays, create an array of objects (could be dynamic or a model class), with specific keys (or properties) for each column.  Those keys are what you need to specify for the dataField.  Check the [example in the livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dpcontrols_6.html).

Comment: o lords ... i need to expand the Object properties dinamically ? is this the aproach ?

Comment: masterData[ iY ][ "column" + c.toString() ] = c;

Comment: That's one way of doing it. Personally, I would create a class for each row with properties: `data[rowIndex] = new RowClass(someData, moreDate, moarData);`

Answer (score 1):

```
How to setup an array or vector as dataprovider to each Column ?
```

In the architecture of a DataGrid, and AdvancedDataGrid individual columns do not have their own, separate, dataProviders.  To set the dataProvider on the component, you can do something like this:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="mainGrid" dataPRovider="{myDataProvider}" >
```

in ActionScript you can set the dataProvider like this:

```
mainGrid.dataProvider = myDataProvider
```

If you have data coming from a myriad of different sources that you need to display in a single DataGrid, you should try to combine that data into a single dataProvider; using some common element, such as a database primary key value.  Creating a single object to contain each separate element should work.  Conceptually something like this:

```
public class myCombinedObject{
 public var commonElement : int;
 public var fromDataProvider1 : myCustomDataClass1;
 public var fromDataProvider2 : myCustomDataClass2;
}
```

From there just write itemRenderers for each column to show the relevant data.

Answer (score 1):

Usually we will set the dataprovider to the Datagrid. And in the columns we can set the datafield, which will take the property from the objects of the dataprovider to be displayed in the particular column. Are you aiming to make the columns coming from different arrays? In that case it will be a tricky one.

Answer (score 1):

I've used an Array of Arrays as a dataProvider. 
You can just set the `dataField` property to the index of the "sub Array".

For example:

```
tempColumn.dataField = iY.toString();
```

This works, (it fills the column with every value from the the sub array [iY]), but I can't recommend doing this because if the order of your data in the sub arrays changes
it could be become difficult to debug...